# Apache Directive Ordering

Tags: apache-2.2

In Apache 2, is the ordering between [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument) and [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) defined and predictable?  I can't find anything in the documentation about this.

For example, if I have the following in a .htaccess file (stripped down from the standard Drupal .htaccess file)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

which will handle a request for a /favicon.ico, the ErrorDocument or the RewriteRule?  Will this always be the same, server-to-server, or can this vary based on how Apache is configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's defined. Mod_Rewrite only works on incoming requests, before Apache has actually looked for the resource. ErrorDocument functions at the level of forming the response (basically the last step).

A slightly oversimplified version of how Apache would work in this case:

- Receive Request
- Modify Request (mod_rewrite and possibly others)
- Get resources specified
- Send response (which would be ErrorDocument if the resource wasn't found)

Comment: So, with the directives above, a request for /favicon.ico would get ignored by the RewriteRule b/c the RewriteCond, but would get punted back to index.php anyway b/c the ErrorDocument?

Comment: A related question would then be, would a request for /some/bad/path get handled by index.html *twice*, once from the RewriteRule and then once from the ErrorDocument?

Comment: Yes to the favicon.ico getting punted by ErrorDocument. No, mod_rewrite doesn't handle requests, it only modifies the incoming request. In this case mod_rewrite would pickup the bad URL and rewrite it to the presumably good "index.php", which would be further processed as if the original request always was for "index.php".